# POSTing a request to the correct URL once HTMLUnit is ignoring the form.setActionAttribute and fom.setAttribute

Tags: java, forms, httpwebrequest, html-parsing, htmlunit

I'm trying to submit a form using `HTMLUnit` but it seems that the action attribute of the form is ignored once the http post is going to the same page.
I'm getting the form on this URL:

http://www.tjse.jus.br/tjnet/consultas/internet/consnomeparte.wsp

And in the source code of this URL we can find that the action attribute is set to this URL:

http://www.tjse.jus.br/tjnet/consultas/internet/respconsnomeparte.wsp

But `HTMLUnit` always post to the first URL.

I'm using fiddler to analyse the request through a real web browser and through `HTMLUnit` and comparing the two `HTTP POST` it's easy to see that `HTMLUnit` is POSTing to the same site, i.e, the first URL mentioned.

I need that `HTMLUnit POST` to the second URL.

If anyone could help me I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Instead of using:

```
HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

I used:

```
button.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something simular to the following.

```
// Enter your username in feild
searchForm.getInputByName("Username").setValueAttribute(schoolID);

//Submit the form and get the result page       
HtmlPage pageResult = (HtmlPage) searchForm.getInputByValue("Search").click();

//Page results in raw html source code  
String html = pageResult.asXml();

    /*
    * filter source code if needed to collect desired data
    */

//login via another server url
page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://"+url);
HtmlForm LoginForm = page.getFormByName("Form1");

// login to web portal
LoginForm.getInputByName("txtUserName").setValueAttribute(username);
LoginForm.getInputByName("txtPassword").setValueAttribute(password);

//Submit the form and get the result page
HtmlPage pageResult = (HtmlPage) LoginForm.getInputByName("btnLogin").click();
```

Note: this htmlUnit code complys with htmlunit 2.15 API